# What do these scripts do? Default Asp.net MVC 3 website

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I made an asp.net mvc and I am looking at the js files(trying to determine what to delete and keep).

I see ones like

```
    jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js
    jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
    MicrosoftAjax.debug.js
    MicrosoftAjax.js
    MicrosoftMvcValidation.debug.js
    MicrosoftMvcValidation.js
    modernizr-1.7.js
```

I am not planning to use any MS ajax tools. I use jquery for all my needs. I will be using jquery validate with data annotations so I know I need that.

Another problem I have is I have no clue how old these files are. I see they have jquery 1.5.1 (they are on 1.7.1 now).

So I want to use the newest files of the ones I need. No point starting a new project with old files.

Comment: i would google each file to know more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MicrosoftAjax and MicrosoftMVCValidation files are the old (MVC2) implementation of ajax validation. The new unobtrusive validation in MVC3 uses jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js and the new unobtrusive Ajax in MVC3 uses jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js. For more details about this check out Brad Wilsons article about [unobtrusive validation in MVC3](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html)

From what you say you only need the unobtrusive validation file (along with jQuery and jQuery Validation).

In order to make sure that you have the latest versions of the files you could use NuGet:

http://nuget.org/packages/jQuery

http://nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Validation

http://nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer to a few of these:

1. `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`

   - This sets up the required script when you do an ajax form post.. in Razor `@using(Ajax.BeginForm...` so that there is no JavaScript to write, you just use the correct server tag and it magically posts the data to your controller, no full page post back.
2. `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`

   - This is the jQuery validation library. Basically when you create your View Model you can set up data annotations on the properties, such as `[Required]` and then the View will render out your input tag with HTML5 data- attributes which this library will pick up on.
3. `modernizr-1.7.js`

   - This library helps with compatibility issues with browsers that don't support CSS3 and HTML5

I'm not sure what the others you listed do specifically, they may have additionall functionality for the libraries listed above. Also, the debug files may just be the unminified versions of the regular file.

I use these scripts in all of my MVC 3 projects. They are powerful, and because we are using the jQuery validation library, it can be extended. I can have a more robust form set up with validation that works with the server code in half the time of a traditional Web Forms solution.